# E: Unable to locate package apt-file while creating docker image

Tags: shell, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am  trying to create image in docker that installs latest jdk,maven,git..

For testing, I am just trying on jdk:

[image: This is my vi editor and my script]

Here I saved this content and run

```
$docker build .
```

[image: This is the error im getting]

Can someone help on this? I have tried all the solutions given in your blog, still not working.

Two things I need to know.

1. the solution for this
2. changes i need to do install all three(jdk,maven,git)
3. or is this error causing for any proxy  setting of the company..?

Comment: okey i will correct this in future... SOrry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead to RUN all your apt-related commands in the **[same `RUN` session](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments)**:

Example:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bzr \
  cvs \
  git \
  mercurial \
  subversion
```

If you are behind a proxy, make sure the [docker daemon has it configured](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy).